# Resistor selection and filter

Tags: filter

I am designing a system with this [module](http://www.vicorpower.com/documents/datasheets/MDCM28AP240M320A50_ds.pdf).
I was refering the example circuit as shown below -

[image: Circuit].

I am in doubt for the R1 wattage and the purpose of the RL circuit (R1 and L1). What does this circuit do ? Is it a filter ? If yes then what type ?

My system draws about 14Amps, so will the wattage be = 0.3*14*14  ?

Answer (score 2):

R1 is stated as being 0.3 ohms and it is in parallel with an inductor of 1uH (stated as having minimized DCR). At DC, the inductor will take (likely) over 90% of the required supply current because its series resistance will be a fraction of an ohm.

So what does it do - if high frequency noise or ripple comes along the impedance of the inductor will rise and you are left with R1 and C1 forming a low pass filter to prevent high frequency noise affecting the module.

Comment: Simply: L1/C1 is a second order lowpass filter, its Q has to be low enough to avoid too much peaking around cut-off frequency which in time domain turns into extra spikes and ringing. Stray resistance in filter elements is not deemed sufficient so extra lossy element R1 is added to damp the sysyem

Comment: @Board-Man Have you done with this Q and A now? If you have you should sign it off. If not then please raise a comment for clarification.